# Se actualizan todos los datos en mysql desde java al modificar solo uno

Tags: java, mysql

Tengo el problema que al intentar modificar solo un dato, lo hace, pero al consultar nuevamente otro dato ya no existe porque todos los datos guardados se modificaron al ultimo dato que modifique, entonces si tenia 10 datos distintos ahora ya son 10 datos iguales.

Dejo el codigo del boton "Modificar"
Leí algo sobre el "where" me parece va en la linea de codigo del PreparedStatement, pero no me queda muy claro

private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
// TODO add your handling code here:

```
    try{
        String ID = textfield1.getText().trim();
        
        Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/administracion?useSSL=false", "root", "123456789");
        PreparedStatement pst = cn.prepareStatement("update usuario set vehiculo = ?, modelo = ?, placas = ?, ultimo_servicio = ?, proximo_servicio = ?");
        
        pst.setString(1, textfield1.getText().trim());
        pst.setString(2, textfield2.getText().trim());
        pst.setString(3, textfield3.getText().trim());
        pst.setString(4, textfield4.getText().trim());
        pst.setString(5, textfield5.getText().trim());
        pst.executeUpdate();
        
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Modificación exitosa.");
    }catch (Exception e){
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola hace mucho no uso bases de datos, pero creo que estas modificando todos los registros y no los estas actualizando, me da a entender que estas modificando todo lo que esta en la columna de por ejemplo vehiculo y remplazas por el nombre que le hallas puesto nuevamente, tendrias que ver el: WHERE vehiculo = "Mercedes"

Comment: Tienes que poner un criterio `WHERE` donde indiques qué filas quieres actualizar, al no poner ese criterio se actualizan todos los registros. En tu código hay confusión, porque recoges un valor `ID` desde `textfield1` y también usas ese valor para pasarlo como dato a una columna llamada `vehiculo`. No queda claro si hay una columna `ID`  en la tabla y se debe filtrar por esa columna o si el filtro debe hacerse por la columna `vehiculo` ¿? Es un detalle fundamental en este caso que deberías aclarar.

Answer (score -1):

Solo te falta hacer el where de que registro quieres cambiar exactamente, el cual deberia ser el id del usuario

```
try{
        String ID = textfield1.getText().trim();
        
        Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/administracion?useSSL=false", "root", "123456789");
        PreparedStatement pst = cn.prepareStatement("update usuario set vehiculo = ?, modelo = ?, placas = ?, ultimo_servicio = ?, proximo_servicio = ? where id=?");/*Este where dice que registro es el que se va a hacer update, en este caso el id del usuario que quieres hacer update*/
        
        pst.setString(1, textfield1.getText().trim());
        pst.setString(2, textfield2.getText().trim());
        pst.setString(3, textfield3.getText().trim());
        pst.setString(4, textfield4.getText().trim());
        pst.setString(5, textfield5.getText().trim());
        pst.setString(6, ID_USR);/*este ID debe ser el de tu usuario*/
        pst.executeUpdate();
        
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Modificación exitosa.");
    }catch (Exception e){
    }
```

Comment: ¿Por qué asumes aquí: `String ID = textfield1.getText().trim();` que el `ID` está en `textfield1` ? Según el código de la pregunta en ese objeto estaría el valor para  `vehiculo`. Tampoco se sabe si `ID` es un valor numérico. Ni siquiera se sabe por qué columna se debería filtrar en este caso para hacer el `UPDATE`. Nada de eso queda claro en la pregunta.

Comment: No lo estoy asumiendo, se lo estoy dejando preparado, si leíste bien la publicación te darás cuenta que le estoy diciendo que el ID que debe poner es el del usuario al que va a actualizar. Al igual que se explica eso dentro del comentario del código.

Comment: Revisa de nuevo tu respuesta: estarías usando el mismo valor como id (set 6) y como dato para la columna `vehiculo` (set 1). Eso no tiene ningún sentido. OP no es claro en su planteamiento y aportar una respuesta sin dilucidar la confusión podría conducir a una confusión aún mayor.